# '|' was unexpected this time

Tags: windows, command-line

I was running the following command to echo pdf names starting with a number. But I get this error

> | was unexpected this time

Code - `FOR /f %a in ('dir /b|findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*.*\.pdf$"') DO echo %a`

I think there is some problem with my cmd.

P.S. - I actually want to delete these files and will replace *echo* command with *del* afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can do your DIR first and pipe it into the command

```
dir /b | FOR /f %a in ('findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*.*\.pdf$"') DO echo %a
```

and if you want to be more efficient with your code given you know in this example you can prefilter the file extension,

```
dir /b *.pdf | FOR /f %a in ('findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*.*\.pdf$"') DO echo %a
```

Comment: The second command (pre filtering based on extension) doesn't work while the first does. Can you tell why? Also can you tell why my code doesn't work? (Where pipe was inside the loop)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Your one isn't working because of the way it interprets commands within the block. 

It's hard to say on the second one being an issue for you without your exact set up, if your directory only contains the files you want to go through anyway just use the first. It's not going to offer much benefit unless your directory contains 10,000+ non pdf files.

Both works for me on my sample directory containing

`aa.pdf
bb.pdf
99.pdf
88.pdf
bb.pdx`

Comment: Sorry for replying late, can you explain more on why my command doesn't work, how it's interpreted and what's the issue. It would be very helpful